# Как найти слова, у которых количество гласных равно количеству согласных и их порядковые номера

Tags: python

Дана следующая строка:

> So she was considering in her own mind, as well as she could, for the
>   hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid,  whether  the  pleasure 
>   of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and 
>   picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran
>   close by her.

Как найти слова, у которых количество гласных букв равно количеству согласных?
Как найти порядковые номера этих слов?

Строку необходимо инициализировать в коде программы.

Answer (score 3):

В принципе, не важно, на каком языке программирования реализовывать решение данной задачи. Важно понять алгоритм.
Подходящий под решение задачи автора выглядит так:

- Составить список гласных букв
- Составить список согласных букв
- Разбить строку на список слов
- Найти количество пересекающихся элементов среди букв в слове и списка гласных
- Найти количество пересекающихся элементов среди букв в слове и списка согласных
- Сравнить количество гласных и согласных букв в слове

---

Согласно [Википедии](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel), важно помнить следующее:

> Буква Y может быть как гласной (в таких словах, как: "cry", "sky", "fly" или  "why"),
>   так и согласной (в таких словах, как: "yellow", "yacht", "yam" или "yesterday").

---

Реализация для варианта, когда `Y` гласная:

```
# coding=utf-8
import re

s = 'So she was considering in her own mind, as well as she could,' \
    + ' for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid, whether the pleasure' \
    + ' of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up' \
    + ' and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes' \
    + ' ran close by her.'
# Определяем списки согласных и гласных букв
vowels = list("aeiouyAEIOUY")
consonants = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ")

# С помощью регулярного выражения разбиваем строку на слова
words = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]+(?:[\'-][a-zA-Z]+)*)', s)

# enumerate нужен для получения индекса слова в строке
for index, word in enumerate(words):
    # Считаем количество гласных/согласных букв в слове
    number_of_vowels = sum(x in vowels for x in word)
    number_of_consonants = sum(x in consonants for x in word)
    # Если количество согласных и гласных букв равно,
    # то выводим порядковый номер текущего слова.
    # Помним, что индекс начинается с 0, а порядковые номера с 1. Нивелируем эту разницу.
    if number_of_vowels == number_of_consonants:
        print(index + 1, word)
```

При написании этого ответа я воспользовался этим ответом на SO:
[Count duplicates between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4775018/2486051)

---

### Update

**Исправления**:

- Исправлена ошибка, из-за которой некорректно обрабатывались слова с повторяющимися буквами
- Исключено использование метода .lower()
- Исправлена путаница между звуками и буквами в ответе
- Удалено ошибочное высказывание о простоте алгоритма реализации
- Добавлено замечание о том, что решение не является универсальным для всех случаев

**Ограничения:**

- В данной реализации словом считается набор букв [a-zA-Z], между которыми может быть дефис или одинарная кавычка.
- В данной реализации аббревиатуры и слова, написанные транскрипцией, не анализируются.

Большое спасибо пользователю [@jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs) за дельный комментарий, в котором он верно подметил ошибки и недочеты в моем ответе.
Рекомендую ознакомиться с его ответом на вопрос [Finding out if half the letters in a word are vowels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548800/2486051) на SO.

Comment: `set()` игнорирует *повторяющиеся* буквы. `[a-z]` и `.lower()` могут не работать даже для английского (лигатуры, комбинирующие символ, итд). Также звуки и буквы это разные вещи. Например, [сравните с ответом, который использует произношение слов, чтобы найти гласные](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548800/4279)

Comment: @jfs большое вам спасибо за то, что указали на ошибки. С `set()` глупо получилось, конечно. Да и верный ответ получается сложнее, чем я ожидал. Усложнять решение до анализа транскрипции не стал, но ссылку на ваш ответ на SO добавил в свое сообщение

Comment: плохо, что ответ, который говорит, что алгоритм *прост*, игнорирует многие сложности обработки естественного языка: например, в Юникоде миллион символов, и как я уже написал, даже английский текст может использовать больше 26 букв. И, конечно, вовсе не очевидно что-такое "слово" (обязано ли оно быть в каком либо словаре?)

Comment: что ж, похоже, вы снова правы, а я поторопился с подобным заявлением. Я подумаю, как я могу улучшить ответ, но весьма вероятно, что мне для этого банально не хватит знаний. В этом случае, мне, возможно, придется удалить ответ, чтобы не вводить пользователей в заблуждение.

Comment: ответ нормальный (если вы посмотрите, то [мой ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548800/4279) также игнорирует не ascii-случай), просто не нужно создавать впечатление, что это тривиальный вопрос в общем случае

Comment: еще раз спасибо, внес необходимые коррективы в ответ